# Compiling an optional cython extension only when possible in setup.py

Tags: python, cython, distutils, setup.py, distutils2

I have a python module fully implemented in python. (For portability reasons.)

The implementation of a small part has been duplicated in a cython module. To improve perfomance where possible.

I know how to install the `.c` modules created by cython with `distutils`. However if a machine has no compiler installed, I suspect the setup will fail even though the module is still usable in pure python mode.

Is there a way to compile the `.c` module if possible but fail gracefully and install without it if compiling is not possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you will have to make some modification both in your `setup.py` and in one `__init__` file in your module.

Let say the name of your package will be "module" and you have a functionality, `sub` for which you have pure python code in the `sub` subfolder and the equivalent C code in `c_sub` subfolder. 
For example in your `setup.py` :

```
import logging
from setuptools.extension import Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
from distutils.errors import CCompilerError, DistutilsExecError, DistutilsPlatformError

logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger(__file__)

ext_errors = (CCompilerError, DistutilsExecError, DistutilsPlatformError, IOError, SystemExit)

setup_args = {'name': 'module', 'license': 'BSD', 'author': 'xxx',
    'packages': ['module', 'module.sub', 'module.c_sub'],
    'cmdclass': {'build_ext': build_ext}
    }

ext_modules = [Extension("module.c_sub._sub", ["module/c_sub/_sub.c"])]

try:
    # try building with c code :
    setup(ext_modules=ext_modules, **setup_args)
except ext_errors as ex:
    log.warn(ex)
    log.warn("The C extension could not be compiled")

    ## Retry to install the module without C extensions :
    # Remove any previously defined build_ext command class.
    if 'build_ext' in setup_args['cmdclass']:
        del setup_args['cmdclass']['build_ext']

    # If this new 'setup' call don't fail, the module 
    # will be successfully installed, without the C extension :
    setup(**setup_args)
    log.info("Plain-Python installation succeeded.")
```

Now you will need to include something like this in your `__init__.py` file (or at any place relevant in your case):

```
try:
    from .c_sub import *
except ImportError:
    from .sub import *
```

In this way the C version will be used if it was build, other-wise the plain python version is used. It assumes that `sub` and `c_sub` will provide the same API.

You can find an [example of setup file](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/setup.py) doing this way in the `Shapely` package. Actually most of the code I posted was copied (the `construct_build_ext` function) or adapted (lines after) from this file.

Comment: For my case I could remove the two if-cases in the last exception block, but I had to instead do `del setup_args['ext_modules']`. Could you explain what your code is doing?

Answer (score 4):

Class [`Extension`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension) has parameter  `optional` in constructor:

> **optional** - specifies that a build failure in the extension should not
>   abort the build process, but simply skip the extension.

Here is also a [link](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201212/skipping_c_extensions.html) to the quite interesting history of piece of code proposed by [mgc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5050917/mgc).

Answer (score 1):

The question [How should I structure a Python package that contains Cython code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505747/how-should-i-structure-a-python-package-that-contains-cython-code)

is related, there the question is how to fallback from Cython to the "already generated C code". You could use a similar strategy to select which of the `.py` or the `.pyx` code to install.

Comment: I do not see how this is applicable. They try importing cython as a python module and fall back to the C-module if importing fails. How do you suggest I try importing the system C compiler in python?

Comment: Indeed, I jumped to conclusions a bit early.