# Optional setup.py dependencies that require the Extension module

Tags: python, numpy, setuptools, setup.py, f2py

I have a main package (say package A) that I want to have an optional dependency. I know that I can use `extras_require` to define optional package dependencies, however I want this optional dependency to use the `Extension` module to build using f2py with additional data files. Is there a way to define an `extras_require` statement to take an extension module? In other words, when I run my `setup.py` file, I can optionally specify that I want to install my wind model, and then it compiles my fortran code using f2py. If the optional wind model dependency is not desired, then the setup.py file runs normally and does not compile the fortran code (useful if a user does not have a fotran compiler installed and does not need this dependency).

The only way I can think to do this currently is by creating a separate package with the wind model and putting this package in the `extras_require` for the main package. The downside to this, is that a user would have to run a separate `setup.py` file for the wind model, and then return to the main package and run the main `setup.py`. To me this is undesirable, and there feels like there should be a way to do this. I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41778153/5111234), however if the cython extension can be downloaded it is downloaded rather than the cython extension needing to be specified by the user.

Comment: Seems to me like you need to split in 2 libraries indeed, where the optimized code with C extension is specified as an extra of the main library.